# Symfony3: There is no extension able to load the configuration for

Tags: php, symfony

I am building an extension to load config files from all installed bundles.

my Extension looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace TheBuggestBot\BotBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration.
 *
 * @link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html
 */
class TheBuggestBotBotExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

I did everything i read from symfony documentation book and the web. Nothing helped me at all...

This is my DependencyInjection/Configuration.php file:

```
<?php

namespace TheBuggestBot\BotBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files.
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html}
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('the_buggest_bot_bot');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('ircbot')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('server')->end()
                        ->integerNode('port')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('username')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('password')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('chanel')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;


        // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
        // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
        // more information on that topic.

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

My Resources/config/config.yml :

```
the_buggest_bot_bot:
    ircbot:
        server:   ""
        port:     6667
        username: ""
        password: ""
        chanel:   ""
```

Error is:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                                           
  There is no extension able to load the configuration for "thebuggestbot" (in /home/dm3ch/TheBuggestBot/test/src/The  
  BuggestBot/BotBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "thebuggestbot", fou  
  nd none
```

P.S. I've read all similar questions on Stack Overflow

**Updated**

Comment: Does you bundle name really have BotBot in it?TheBuggestBotBotExtension?  The prefixes have to match exactly.

Comment: Yes bundle's name is TheBuggestBotBotBundle. I tried with the_buggest_bot_bot as symfony generated, it also doesn't work.

Comment: Stick a die statement in your extension just to verify that is is getting loaded.  I still suspect that it is not.  Needless to say, make sure the bundles is in AppKernel as well.

Comment: I've added die in load function in Extension class. And it exiting with die message. So load function is called

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and fix it.

To register an extension you need to have same name for bundle and you extension. So, if you wanna enable your extension as `the_buggest_bot_bot`, your extension file must be named as `TheBuggestBotBotExtention` and bundle must be named as `TheBuggestBotBotBundle`.

Or if you don't wanna change your Bundle name, you must rename your extension to the same name as bundle. Or you can manually register extension:

```
class TheBuggestBotBotBundle extends Bundle
{

  public function getContainerExtension()
  {
    if ($this->extension === null) {
        $this->extension = new TheBuggestBotBotExtension();
    }

    return $this->extension;
  }
}
```