# Symfony Bundle Load YML Configuration

Tags: php, symfony, routes, yaml, bundle

Since I am new to Symfony and I couldn't manage to find some useful information in google I decided to write to you. 
I've read about the way of loading custom DI alias information from a dependency injector in your bundle and how to create a Configuration class that will expose the alias structure. However I am to some extend confused how I can create a file, for example **routing.yml**, in my **AcmeBundle/Resources/config/** folder and read the data from it. E.g:

```
some_alias:
    resource: "@AcmeBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

I want to make a bundle with routing, independent from the main configuration files in the app folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733150/symfony3-there-is-no-extension-able-to-load-the-configuration-for this article is another example of the same problem but it has not been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your bundle routing.yml in your `WhateverBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` and the in the app/routing.yml just include your bundle's routes.

```
mybundleorwhatever:
    resource: "@WhateverBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

Comment: Just to clarify: there is no way to have a bundle's routing file included automatically. Adding the above to an app's config must be part of the bundle installation procedure.